# Problem with a foreign key referencing a primary key which is also part of an unique key (MariaDB)

Tags: mariadb, foreign-key, unique-constraint

I created a database using MariaDb. I have the following `author` table (with `id` as primary key), which is extended by two other tables,  `author_personal` and `author_corporate`, representing two different kinds of author and having different fields:

```
CREATE TABLE `author` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author_type` char(1) NOT NULL,
  -- other fields
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `author_UN` (`id`,`author_type`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `author_CHECK_type` CHECK (`author_type` in ('P','C'))
);

CREATE TABLE `author_personal` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  -- other fields
  `author_type` char(1) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ('P') VIRTUAL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `author_personal_FK` (`id`,`author_type`),
  CONSTRAINT `author_personal_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`id`, `author_type`) REFERENCES `author` (`id`, `author_type`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE `author_corporate` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `corporate_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `corporate_acronym` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `author_type` char(1) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ('C') VIRTUAL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `author_corporate_FK` (`id`,`author_type`),
  CONSTRAINT `author_corporate_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`id`, `author_type`) REFERENCES `author` (`id`, `author_type`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Although `author.id` would be enough, I decided to create an UNIQUE KEY (`id`, `author_type`) to be referenced by the foreign key in the two other tables, so that it would be impossible to reference from `author_personal` an `author` which is not flagged as P, and from `author_corporate` an `author` which is not flagged as C.

The problem rises when I want to reference `author` using the primary key, like in this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `work_authors` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `work_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `author_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  -- other fields
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `work_authors_FK` (`work_id`),
  KEY `work_authors_FK_author` (`author_id`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `work_authors_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`work_id`) REFERENCES `work` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `work_authors_FK_author` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `author` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Both DBeaver and PhpMyAdmin think that `work_authors_FK_author` references `author_UN` instead of the actual primary key (`author.id`).

[image: DBeaver Foreign Key description]

This means that in DBeaver I am not able to click on the values in `work_authors.author_id` and open the referenced record in `authors` because I get the following error:

`Entity [davide_library.author] association [work_authors_FK_author] columns differs from referenced constraint [author_UN] (1<>2)`

I created the foreign keys using DBeaver. Although I selected `PRIMARY` as the unique key, in the list of foreign keys it always show `author_UN` as the referenced object. I don't know if this behavior depends on MariaDB or DBeaver.

**My question is:**

Is there any way to explicitily reference in the DDL the primary key instead of the unique key?

**or, alternatively:**

Is there a different way, other than the UNUQUE constraint, to check that `author_personal` references only authors flagged with P, and the same for `author_corporate`?

Comment: You'll need a trigger to enforce the exclusive subtype.

Comment: Do you mean that I should replace the UNIQUE constraint with a trigger (I didn't know about them) and use only the ID in relations?

Comment: Yes.  I'm not an expert in MariaDB so I can't show you how to write the trigger, but you will need to query the `author` table to verify the `author_type` matches the table the record is being inserted into.  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/trigger-overview/

Comment: Thank you, knowing about triggers is helpful enough!

Comment: Have you tried author_type as a stored column? You can also try it as a normal column: `author_type char(1) DEFAULT 'C' NOT NULL` AND a CHECK (author_type ='C')

Comment: Unless there is a flaw in Mariadb, a trigger should not be needed

Comment: @Lennart do you mean in the `author_corporate` table? This is a working alternative to the virtual column, which however is not part of my problem. I would still need the `author_corporate_FK` constraint to ensure that the corrisponding record in `author` is flagged as C. A solution could be `CHECK((SELECT author_type FROM author WHERE author_corporate.id = author.id) = 'C')` in `author_corporate` (or a similar thing in `author`) but SQL syntax does not allow that.

Comment: Yes, my hypothesis is that DBeaver and PhpMyAdmin are confused because of the virtual column. The SQL is valid as far as I can see. You can check what MariaDB did in `Information_Schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariadDB seems to handle it correctly. According to [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=c6abde6772f45fe2b5b5bb7b9b33a9c7) the information_schema is correct, so the problem seems to be with your tools:

```
SELECT table_name, constraint_name, referenced_table_name, unique_constraint_name 
FROM information_schema.referential_constraints;

table_name          constraint_name         referenced_table_name   unique_constraint_name
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
author_personal1    author_personal_FK      author1                 author_UN
work_authors1       work_authors_FK_author  author1                 PRIMARY
```